# how to show a list of links to objects saved in a List object on a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I am new to programming in c# and to WPF both. this is my first project. 
I have a List of Pet objects I created, called myPets, which can be changed by the program user (new Pet objects can be added to the list in runtime) and I wish to show a link to every object on this list in a window (the link would open a new window called WatchPet that would show the object to screen). I know how to do this with a single object, or with a non changing list of objects, but how do I do that if the list keeps changing? should I use a list, a grid, another data object?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is your friend: [ObservableCollection in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ObservableCollection instead of the List.

Example:

```
ObservableCollection<Pet> pets = new ObservableCollection<Pet>();
```

Any bindings you have will automatically refresh when you add/delete or change items from the observable collection.

More info on [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Edit:**

For that to work you need to do the following:

1. Change the ItemsSource binding to "{Binding MyPets}" (MyPets is a public property in your class behind the xaml file and points to your real collection);
2. Add a DataTemplate to the list like this:

   ```
   <ListBox {...}>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name"}/>
           <!--You can modify this template to suit your needs.-->
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   ```
3. In the constructor of the class behind the xaml file you must set the DataContext = this;

Regards,
Mishu

Comment: thank you for your answer. however, I use window and not  form, and I run into a problem. this is my list:
`myPets = new ObservableCollection<Pets>();` its found in a class called interface, inside another object called User, as a field. so linking to it looks like this:
`mypets.ItemsSource = MainWindow.program._currUser.myPets;`
but what I'm trying to do is display the field `name` inside each `Pets` object in the list, in my listview. and I'm unable to.

Comment: this is the xaml: `<ListView Height="316" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="628,152,0,0" Name="mypets" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="500" ItemsSource="{Binding name}"/>`

Comment: thank you. I tried this like you said, but the VS10 wont accept the xaml. it cannot find `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` in the type Listbox.
perhaps I need to include something I do not know about?
( the cs page does include `System.Windows.Controls`)

Comment: Try to add that declaration into the `<ListBox></ListBox>`.

Comment: Mishu, thank you so much for your help! it works now, the problem was in another part of the code. many thanks!